# How to change hibernate query from insert to update before commit

Tags: java, hibernate

we're having a problem with hibernate performing `INSERT` query instead of `UPDATE`.
**Background:** we're running two long-term transactions in parallel, modifying the same table. While the transactions run, we use `entityManager.merge()`,  but only flush to the db in the end, right before the commit.
So, **transaction a**  commits successfully. Few minutes later, when **transaction b** tries to flush, it fails with [`ConstraintViolationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintViolationException.html) caused by having duplicate keys in the common table. 
We assume that when **transaction b** merges, **transaction a** hasn't commited *yet*, the entity hasn't been written to the DB and so an `INSERT` query is created. However, **transaction a** commits before **transaction b** and inserts the entity to the DB, so at that moment we need to change the query in **transaction b** to update.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Hibernate instead of pure JPA, you can use `Session#saveOrUpdate`.  You can get access to the Hibernate session with `Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);`

Comment: thank you, but i suppose that that what merge doing, no?

Comment: They behave slightly differently.  For `merge` to work  the entityManager needs to know the object exists. It doesn't check the DB first. As an alternative to using the Hibernate session, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36241661/1245752